# How to make cargo enter the correct path to source files of stdlib while adding debuginfo to exectuable

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am debugging a rust program but whenever I try to step into any standard library function, gdb (or lldb) can't find stdlib source files, giving error like this:

```
/rustc/3c235d5600393dfe6c36eeed34042efad8d4f26e/src/libcore/slice/mod.rs: No such file or directory.
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
cargo new test
```

test/src/main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    let a:Vec<char> = Vec::new();
}
```

```
$ cd test
$ cargo build
$ rust-gdb target/debug/test

...

(gdb) b main.rs:1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4a04: file src/main.rs, line 2.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/xyz/code/rust/test/target/debug/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, test::main () at src/main.rs:2
2           let a: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

(gdb) s
alloc::vec::Vec<T>::new ()
    at /rustc/3c235d5600393dfe6c36eeed34042efad8d4f26e/src/liballoc/vec.rs:318
318     /rustc/3c235d5600393dfe6c36eeed34042efad8d4f26e/src/liballoc/vec.rs: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your project directory structure? How are you running lldb and gdb? From what directory are you running them? Consider making a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are running in vscode on windows you can add the following to your launch.json:

```
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/rustc/3c235d5600393dfe6c36eeed34042efad8d4f26e": "${env:USERPROFILE}\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\src\\rust"
        }
```

For further reference see: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-how-to-step-into-std-source-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code/25319/6